# installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, plyr

By installing the package using the following command

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)
```

I got this error.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/maven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--2017-09-07 10:20:11--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.4.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.192.188.135
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.192.188.135|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 392451 (383K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/Rtmp4gqHuh/downloaded_packages/plyr_1.8.4.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13% 1.12M 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 2.01M 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39% 4.67M 0s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52% 5.25M 0s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65% 3.44M 0s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78% 5.00M 0s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 91% 5.00M 0s
   350K .......... .......... .......... ...                  100% 5.43M=0.1s

2017-09-07 10:20:12 (2.94 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/Rtmp4gqHuh/downloaded_packages/plyr_1.8.4.tar.gz’ saved [392451/392451]

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/maven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/maven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/00LOCK-plyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp4gqHuh/downloaded_packages’
```

I am using both latest version of R and RStudio on ubuntu.

Any suggestion to install that package?

Comment: Could you please check in the installation for any directory that shows locked and if so remove it and install again

Comment: I could not understand what you want to say.

Comment: Sandeep, the error already told you --- Try removing ‘/home/maven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/00LOCK-plyr’